# Query in graphql API call using flurl

Tags: json, api, graphql, flurl

I have an API in GraphQL and trying to call it. First call to get first 50 records works fine, my query is,

```
var firstQuery = "{\"query\": \"{products(first: 100) {totalCount edges {node {id,name,brand{name},prices{quantity,price},tags{name},barcodes{code},lastCost,cost,caseQuantity,image} cursor} pageInfo { endCursor hasNextPage }}}\"}";

var task = flurlAutUrl
            .WithHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
            .WithHeader("Accept", "application/json")
            .PostStringAsync(firstQuery)
            .ReceiveJson();

        task.Wait();
```

when trying to get the next 50 records, getting an error as 400, bad request, at task.wait()
my query for second page records,

```
var afterQueryLeft = "{\"query\": \"{products(first: 100 after:";
var afterQueryRight = ") {totalCount edges {node {id,name,brand{name},prices{quantity,price},tags{name},barcodes{code},lastCost,cost,caseQuantity,image} cursor} pageInfo { hasNextPage, endCursor }}}\"}";


while (hasNextPage)
        {
            //var afterQuery = "{\"query\": \"{products(first: 100 after:"\"lastCursor) {totalCount edges {node {id,name,brand{name},prices{quantity,price},tags{name},barcodes{code},lastCost,cost,caseQuantity,image} cursor} pageInfo { endCursor hasNextPage }}}\"}";

            var nextPageQuery =  afterQueryLeft + "\"" + lastCursor + "\"" + afterQueryRight;
            var nextPageTask = flurlAutUrl
                .WithHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                .WithHeader("Accept", "application/json")
                .PostStringAsync(nextPageQuery)
                .ReceiveJson();

            nextPageTask.Wait();
}
```

What is wrong in my query, this query works fine in postman (200 ok)

Comment: Have you double-checked the value of `nextPageQuery` against what you're using in Postman (i.e. extracted it via the debugger and pasted it straight into Postman)? I don't know your API, but it seems a little odd that the "after" value is quoted - should it be?

Comment: Also, should there be a comma between the arguments to the "products" query?

Comment: that's one of [many] reason to use variables ( https://graphql.org/learn/queries/#variables ), not string manipulations - `after` can be simply undefined for first 'loop' (do_while) - values (`lastCursor`, `hasNextPage`) properly extracted?

Comment: +1 to @xadm's comment above - my comments are just to help with the immediate problem. Even if this code didn't have problems, it'd still be very fragile and hard-to-read with this string concatenation approach.

Comment: My first query gives proper result, but second query with after:"last_cursor" doesnt.

Comment: In postman, I copied the query string while debugging, that too gives the correct result (next 50 records)

Comment: In that case, if you can't see any difference between the queries, I'd suggest firstly debugging on the server, if it's your server, and if not, perhaps you could inspect the payload using something like fiddler to see exactly what your API is sending, compared to what Postman is sending, as they must be different.

Comment: It would probably help if you showed the Postman screenshot in your question...

Answer (score 1):

The comments on the original question are correct in that GraphQL variables should be used. In addition it should be Async code using async/await too.

But, regardless, retrieving and processing paginated GraphQL results can still be a real pain even with Flurl...

So I've published the [FlurlGraphQL](https://github.com/cajuncoding/FlurlGraphQL) library (extensions to Flurl) which greatly simplifies working with GraphQL & Flurl.

With [FlurlGraphQL](https://github.com/cajuncoding/FlurlGraphQL) the original question can be implemented as:

```
//You don't have to work with the raw Json as it's alot more work/code 
//and the Library will greatly simplify this with a model such as 
//(educated guesses on data types, etc.)...
public class Product {
    public string Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public ProductBrand Brand {get; set;} //Define the Branch class also...
    public ProductPrices Prices  {get; set;} //Define the Prices class also...
    public ProductTags Tags {get; set;} //Define the Tags class also...
    public ProductBarcodes Barcodes {get; set;} //Define the Barcode class also...
    public decimal LastCost {get; set;}
    public decimal Cost {get; set;}
    public int CaseQuantity {get; set;}
    public string Image {get; set;}
}

var flurlGraphQL = await flurlAutUrl
    .WithGraphQLQuery(@"
        query ($first: Int, $after: String) {
            products(first: $first, after: $after) {
                totalCount
                edges {
                    node {
                        id
                        name
                        brand {
                            name
                        }
                        prices {
                            quantity
                            price
                        }
                        tags {
                            name
                        }
                        barcodes {
                            code
                        }
                        lastCost
                        cost
                        caseQuantity
                        image
                    }
                    cursor
                }
                pageInfo {
                    endCursor
                    hasNextPage
                }
            }
        }
    ");
    
//Get the First Page (we do not specify any value for $after)
var firstPageResults = flurlGraphQL
    .SetGraphQLVariables(new { first = 100 });
    .PostGraphQLQueryAsync()
    .ReceiveGraphQLConnectionResults<Product>();

//The Library makes getting the various Paging details 
//significantly easier...
var endCursor = firstPageResults.PageInfo.EndCursor;
    
//Get the Second Page using the End Cursor of the first, and this time 
//only retrieve 50 (per original question)...
var secondPageResults = flurlGraphQL
    .SetGraphQLVariables(new { first = 50, after = endCursor });
    .PostGraphQLQueryAsync()
    .ReceiveGraphQLConnectionResults<Product>();

foreach(var result in secondPageResults)
{
    //...process your results...
}
```

But this is actually even easier if you just want to enumerate the pages and get your data:

```
//Using the same initialized Flurl GraphQL query above we could async
//stream/enumerate all the pages...
var pagesAsyncEnumerable = flurlGraphQL
    .SetGraphQLVariables(new { first = 100 });
    .PostGraphQLQueryAsync()
    .ReceiveGraphQLConnectionPagesAsyncEnumerable<Product>();
        
await foreach (var page in pagesAsyncEnumerable)
{
    //...Process each page as a stream of Async Enumerable pages...
    //NOTE: The library has APIs to get ALL pages in a single blocking 
    //       request or get them in an IEnumerable too...
}
```